# MVC3 - View is not updating with new data on Viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to update my view with new viewmodel data, but everytime I load the viewmodel, it shows correct data in viewmodel, even in the data in jquery success call, but it won't update the view.

I am pasting the code below, kindly check and let me know, what I am doing wrong?

I am pissed off with this, since two days.

**ViewModel**

```
namespace CRMTest.Models.ViewModels
{
public class ContactViewModel
{
    private Xrm.Contact item;

    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string CompReg { get; set; }
    public string OurRef { get; set; }
    public string RefType { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public string Salutation { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string ClientServices { get; set; }
    public bool ContactByTel { get; set; }
    public bool ContactByEmail { get; set; }
    public bool ContactByLetter { get; set; }
    public bool ContactByFax { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public ContactViewModel(Xrm.Contact item)
    {
        ContactName = item.Address1_Name;
        Address1 = item.Address1_Line1;
        Address2 = item.Address1_Line2;
        Address3 = item.Address1_Line3;
        Town = item.Address1_City;
        County = item.Address1_County;
        Postcode = item.Address1_PostalCode;
        OurRef = item.NickName;
        Contact = item.Salutation+" "+item.FullName;
        Salutation = item.Salutation+" "+item.LastName;
        Position = item.JobTitle;
        Telephone = item.Address1_Telephone1;
        Fax = item.Address1_Fax;
        Mobile = item.Address1_Telephone2;
        Email = item.EMailAddress1;
        Website = item.WebSiteUrl;
    }        
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //CRM Start
        Session.Add("ServiceProxy", serviceProxy);

        //CRM End

        var service = Session["ServiceProxy"] as Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService;
        service = (IOrganizationService)serviceProxy;


        if (service != null)
        {              
            using (var context2 = new XrmServiceContext(service))
            {
                var contacts = context2.ContactSet.FirstOrDefault(); 
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    var contactsViewModel = new ContactViewModel(contacts);

                return View(contactsViewModel);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Service proxy is missing is session state. Did you log in?");
            return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string strSearchParam)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return PartialView("FindCustomer", strSearchParam);

            return View(strSearchParam);
        }

        if (service != null)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            using (var context2 = new XrmServiceContext(service))
            {
                var contacts = context2.ContactSet.Where(c => c.NickName.Equals(strSearchParam)).FirstOrDefault();

                if (contacts != null)
                {                       
                    var contactsViewModel = new ContactViewModel(contacts);
                    ModelState.Clear();

                    return View("Index",contactsViewModel);
                }
                else
                    return View();
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
@model CRMTest.Models.ViewModels.ContactViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"    type="text/css" media="all" /> 
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">  </script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

 @using (Html.BeginForm("frmContactForm"))
 {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true); 
<div id="mainForm">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ContactName)</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactName)</td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Our Ref/Type")</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.OurRef)</td><td><input id="Contact" name="Contact" type="text" value="Mrs Lakhbir"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1)</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Address1)</td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Contact/Salu'n")</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Contact)</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Salutation)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address2)</td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Position")</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Position)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address3)</td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Tel/Fax")</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Telephone)</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fax)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("Town/City")</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Town)</td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Mobile")</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Mobile)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.County)</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.County)</td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Client Services")</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientServices)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Postcode)</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Postcode)</td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Contact by")</td><td colspan="2">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ContactByTel) Tel&nbsp;@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ContactByEmail) Email&nbsp;@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ContactByLetter) Letter&nbsp;@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ContactByFax) Fax</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompReg)</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompReg)</td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Email")</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("1 of 5906")</td><td><input type="button" id="btnFind" value="Find" />&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="btnEdit" value="Edit" />&nbsp;<input type="button" name="btnNew" value="New" disabled="disabled" />&nbsp;<input type="button" name="btnAccount" value="Account" disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td>@Html.Label("Website")</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Website)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

}

```
<div id="findCustomer">
    <div class="popup_content radius" >
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.Label("OurRef")</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBox("txtOurRef")<br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.ContactName)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.ContactName, new { @class = "form_input radius" })<br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.CompReg)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.CompReg, new { @class = "form_input radius" })<br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Address1)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Address1, new { @class = "form_input radius" })<br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Address2)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Address2, new { @class = "form_input radius" })<br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Telephone)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Telephone, new { @class = "form_input radius" })<br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Postcode)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Postcode, new { @class = "form_input radius" })<br /></td>
            </tr>
            @*  <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" class="submit submit_green fltl"></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btnClose" value="Cancel" class="submit submit_green fltl"></td>
            </tr>*@
        </table>
    </div>
</div> 

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btnFind")
                .click(function () {
                    $("#findCustomer").dialog("open");
                });

            $("#findCustomer")
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 330,
                    width: 350,
                    modal: true,
                    title: 'Find Customer',
                    resizable: false,
                    buttons: {
                        'Search': function () {
                            var id = $("#txtOurRef").val();
                            $("#mainForm").load(id);
                            var form = $('#frmContactForm');
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '/Contacts/Index',
                                data: { strSearchParam: id },
                                cache: false,
                                //dataType: 'json',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    alert($("#mainForm"));
                                    alert(data);
                                    //form.replaceWith(data);
                                    $("#mainForm").load(data);
                                    $("#findCustomer").dialog("close");
                                },
                                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { debugger;/*see what happened */ }
                            })
                        },
                        'Cancel': function () {
                            $("#findCustomer").dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('Fail');
                    }   
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You use

```
 $("#mainForm").load(data);
```

but if data isn't a url, you should use

```
 $("#mainForm").html(data);
```

probably you just want to replace the contents of mainform, so then it would be something like this:

```
 $("#mainForm").html($(data).find("#mainForm").html());
```

Comment: I have removed the unwanted code to fetch the data, as it has not any impact on functioning, it populates the data in viewmodel and I can track it until it displays in view.

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean, but in  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string strSearchParam) the code never gets inside the if (service != null)? Is that correct?

Comment: I load the session with connection and other stuff, which is required to load the data. which works fine and it gets inside the if condition, so please ignore that, my problem is once it gets inside and reach in the view. If you see the ajax call in view, I have alerted the data which I get and I get updated data alerted there.

Comment: Ok sorry, couldn't see the context. If the alert has your updated data it's probably in the loading of the html. See my updated answer.

Comment: I tried the html(data) before but it was not working that's why I tried .load method. Anyways, I tried what you suggested but it will show the empty screen and won't display anything. But if I see the view source, it has got all the required data. Why is that?